# Proxmox ARP cache causing virtual machines MAC to change?

Tags: proxmox, arp

I am having an issue with Proxmox and ARP changing the MAC address of virtual machines.

`arp -a` returns:

```
ipxxx.ip-51-89-201.eu (51.89.201.xxx) at fe:ed:de:ad:be:ef [ether] on vmbr0
```

This virtual machines MAC should not be that. Rebooting (the virtual machine) or flushing ARP cache fixes it temporarily.

The MAC `fe:ed:de:ad:be:ef` (feed dead beef) is a sign of someone flooding the network with a gratuitous arp? 51.195.234.254 is the gateway address on the machine

```
? (51.195.234.254) at fe:ed:de:ad:be:ef [ether] on vmbr0
```

Proxmox node /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


auto enp193s0f0
iface enp193s0f0 inet manual


auto enp133s0f0
iface enp133s0f0 inet manual


auto enp133s0f1
iface enp133s0f1 inet manual


auto enp193s0f1
iface enp193s0f1 inet manual


iface enp9s0f3u2u2c2 inet manual


auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
    bond-slaves enp193s0f0 enp193s0f1
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-mode 802.3ad
    bond-xmit-hash-policy layer2+3


auto bond1
iface bond1 inet manual
    bond-slaves enp133s0f0 enp133s0f1
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-mode 802.3ad
    bond-xmit-hash-policy layer2+3


auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address 51.195.234.xxx/24
    gateway 51.195.234.254
    bridge-ports bond0
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0




    post-up ip route add 51.89.201.xxx/28 dev vmbr0
    post-up echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

I have tried adding the following but it hasn't done much

```
net.ipv4.conf.vmbr0.arp_ignore=1
net.ipv4.conf.vmbr0.arp_announce=2
```

The only temporary fix I know now is to clear the current ARP cache

```
ip -s -s neigh flush all
```